TextWrapping does not work with grid container in wpf
I have the following code, the texbox text does not use the grid witdh and takes all width required  to display the text. The width of the TextBlock must be dynamic. I need it to flow with the window as it is resized. I tried to use a grid instead stackpanel to ErrorTemplate but it does not work

<Style TargetType="PasswordBox" x:Key="passwordBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel > <!--the only thing that worked for me was set stackpanel witdh to 300-->
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,5,0" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5F7F9" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#767676" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#F5F7F9" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 10" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,10,10" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#d9d9d9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,5,50" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

window's code:
<Window x:Class="Vistas.prueba"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:w="clr-namespace:Vistas"
        Title="prueba" Height="300" Width="500">
    <Grid Width="300" x:Name="gd" Background="Aqua">
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Contrasena" />
          <PasswordBox Name="txtContrasena" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource passwordBoxStyle}" w:BoundPasswordBox.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Usu_Contrasena, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

the class used to bind a PasswordBox
class BoundPasswordBox
    { 
            private static bool _updating = false;

           
            public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPasswordProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword",
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(BoundPasswordBox),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));

           
            public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject d)
            {
                return (string)d.GetValue(BoundPasswordProperty);
            }

            
            public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject d, string value)
            {
                d.SetValue(BoundPasswordProperty, value);
            }

           
            private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(
                DependencyObject d,
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                PasswordBox password = d as PasswordBox;
                if (password != null)
                {
                    // Disconnect the handler while we're updating.
                    password.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;
                }

                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    if (!_updating)
                    {
                        password.Password = e.NewValue.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    password.Password = string.Empty;
                }
                // Now, reconnect the handler.
                password.PasswordChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(PasswordChanged);
            }

           
            static void PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PasswordBox password = sender as PasswordBox;
                _updating = true;
                SetBoundPassword(password, password.Password);
                _updating = false;
            }

            
    }



If a StackPanel works for you, what is your issue?

Your Grid has only one row (by default); so your "password box" is sitting on top of your "text block".
